# What does "dual" of a line mean?

Tags: geometry

I was solving a question and it stated,

We define dual of a line $y=mx+c$ to be point $(m,-c)$. Consider a set of $n$ non vertical lines, $n>3$,passing through a point $(1,1)$. Then the duals of these line will always

(1) be the same   (2) lie on a circle (3) lie on a line (4) forms vertices of a polygon with positive area

Comment: I believe this comes from projective geometry. Try googling words such as "dual" and "pojective" and "geometry" and "line" and "point" together.

Comment: Your question: "What is the meaning of "dual" in this context". Answer: Take it as a definition; don't try to make connections for example with vector spaces. There is a theory behind, i.e., Hough transform, that uses this concept, but don't bother. Concentrate on forming an algebraic constraint from the fact that $y=mx+p$ passes through point $(x,y)=(1,1)$.

Comment: Ok I'll do that

Comment: See for example dias 12-13-14 in (http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/ifi/INF4300/h09/undervisningsmateriale/hough09.pdf)

Comment: @JeanMarie can't see pdf here , any link for pdf won't work

Comment: May I ask you your country ?

Comment: @JeanMarie: India (look at the profile).

Answer (score 1):

Any line $L$ with a slope $m$ passing through $(1, 1)$ will have this equation:

$$y-1=m(x-1)$$

$$y = mx+(1-m)$$

Therefore, the dual of this line is $(m, -(1-m))$, or $(m, m-1)$.

Keep in mind that for us, $m$ is a variable.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Sure thanks but I want to know what does "dual of line" means here.

Comment: This really does not even address the question.

Comment: @AlexM. I only realized that after I wrote the answer, and I decided to leave the answer in case somebody stumbles on this question in the future and is interested in the answer to the multiple choice question. I honestly don't even understand the actual question though; the dual of a line was clearly defined as $(m, -c)$. I'm not sure what else could be an answer to the question "What does dual of a line mean?"

Comment: @Ovi: In algebraic geometry, there is a notion of "dual variety", so I believe that the OP was asking about some deep meaning of the word "dual" as used here. Oftentimes, the duals of objects contain plenty of information about the original objects (think of Pontriagin duals, for instance).

Comment: The document is written by a lecturer from Norway, Anne Solberg, that has given her mail address in the document: maybe you could contact her at anne@ifi.uio.no

Comment: @Alex M. Yes it can be that. But, less far than that, as I have indicated, it is almost certain that it deals with the so called "Hough Transform", a kind of avatar of Radon Transform, very used in image processing.